# Is it possible to render HTML from a ReactComponentB?

Tags: scalajs-react

I've got an existing HTML page that I have transcribed into scalajs-react scalatags in a ReactComponentB object, but the output is slightly different from the original HTML.  Is there a way I can render out the HTML from the ReactComponentB so that I can compare it with my original HTML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like `React.renderToStaticMarkup()` is what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks.  That was it.